# Which kernel version needed for Android 4.x porting?

Tags: linux-kernel, android-hardware, android-kernel

I want my device porting to Android 4.x version. What kernel version should I use with Android 4.x and why?

Unfortunately I can not find out what kernel they use Android 4.x and why that kernel versio

Comment: Most probably 3.2 and above. I'm sorry, I'm not expert in Android, but my tablet works on 3.2 (Android 4.3), original Android. Tablet is a Asus Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

This are the current available kernel versions:

- 4.0.x Ice Cream San, kernel 3.0.1
- 4.1.x Jelly Bean, kernel 3.0.31
- 4.2.x Jelly Bean, kernel 3.4.0
- 4.3   Jelly Bean, kernel 3.4.39

The question is more I can run Android 4.x with kernel version 2.6.32?